# Getting Incorrect string value: '\x92\xB7\xFF\xF3' while using AES_ENCRYPT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I know and I've researched a lot of very similar problems in Stackoverflow. I've tried all solutions and nothing has worked to me.

I've used following query to insert user records

```
INSERT INTO `user`(user_name,`password`) VALUE ("D001",AES_ENCRYPT('password1234',"hello"))
```

When I do this, I'm getting

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Execution Time : 00:00:00:046
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:046

Warning Code : 1366
Incorrect string value: '\x92\xB7\xFF\xF3\xD1\xF6...' for column 'password' at row 1
---------------------------------------------------
```

with the above updation, row is getting inserted with just user_user but password is empty.

**What I've done by referring similar problems are as follows**
1) SET NAMES utf8mb4
2) ALTER TABLE `user` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
3) Inside  my.ini configuration file, I've added **character_set_server=utf8mb4**

Still I'm getting the same problem. How to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**
Problem is not specific to just password. What I wanted to do to scramble all required columns so that users can't see those columns normally.
So, I've used AES_ENCRYPT.

Comment: This code should never work. You are storing plain passwords in the log files!

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Updated in the question

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. Hash them. See [tag:password-encryption] for why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are storing binary data in a char,varchar or text column.

Either

1. store your data as hex:

   INSERT INTO `user`(user_name,`password`) VALUE ("D001",HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('password1234',"hello")))

And use the `UNHEX()` function when you need to decrypt it; `AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(password),"hello")`

Or

2. convert your `password` column to a type that can store binary data, such as the  `binary` or `varbinary` type.

Comment: Updated in the question. Password column I've just used as a reference. What exactly I wanted to do it to mask all(not only for password). So that the data can't be seen normally to any user.

If that's the case, do I have to make all columns to varbinary? Or any other way?

Comment: Like for example, in an while inserting I scramble the data with a key, And when I use select with the same key, I see the actual data.

Comment: `AES_ENCRYPT()` produces binary data.  If you want to store the result of `AES_ENCRYPT()` in a column then you either need to convert the result of `AES_ENCRYPY())` to hex so you can store it in a column of type varchar/char/text , or you need to convert your column to a type that can store binary data.

Comment: Understood. And what if I wanted to do the same as you've mentioned to columns those contain floating point values?

Comment: There's no difference, you need to do the same thing - a float or int column can not store binary data,(Ofcorse, encrypting all columns like that in a SQL database sounds like the wrong approach for whatever you are doing.)

Comment: Ok. Great. I'll do the same to floating points too.
Yes. It's a wrong approach. But that's what my boss wants :)
Is there any other options to make this approach right? I mean, I want a user to view the content of a table who must have some sort of key or something like that. I still want user to access the database and tables, but unless he has some sort of key, He can't see the actual data at all.

Comment: You'd build an application that displays only the allowed data from the database to the logged in user, and not give the user directly access to the database.